# Get and sort all views in a database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have some code that gets a list of all views&folders in a database. The problem is everything is very poorly organized. The list of views shows as almost random, although I assume there is some order...

Is there a way to take the list of all the views that show on the dialog prompt, and then sort the list alphabetically?

```
Sub Initialize
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim w As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim dbSource As NotesDatabase, dbDest As NotesDatabase
Dim source As NotesView, dest As NotesView
Dim vc As NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim docDest As NotesDocument
Dim ve As NotesViewEntry
Dim folders() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ret, rez

Set dbSource = s.CurrentDatabase

ForAll v In dbSource.Views
    If v.IsFolder Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve folders( i - 1 ) As String
        folders( i - 1 ) = v.Name
    End If
End ForAll

ret = w.Prompt( PROMPT_OKCANCELLISTMULT, "Folder selection", "Select one or more folders to move.", folders(0), folders )
If IsEmpty( ret ) Then
    MessageBox "User canceled", , "Folder not selected"
    Exit Sub
Else


      rez = w.Prompt( 13, "Database selection", "Choose the database to move the folder to" )


      ForAll f In ret  


        Set source = dbSource.GetView( f )
        Set vc = source.AllEntries





          Set dbDest = s.GetDatabase( rez(0), rez(1), False )
          Call dbDest.EnableFolder( f )

          Set ve = vc.GetFirstEntry
          Do Until ve Is Nothing
              Set docDest = ve.Document.CopyToDatabase( dbDest )
              Call docDest.PutInFolder( f )
              Set ve = vc.GetNextEntry( ve )
        Loop

        Call vc.RemoveAllFromFolder( f )
             Call source.Remove
         End ForAll
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this subroutine to sort the `folders` array before you include it in your prompt method.

Just call `ShellSort(folders)` before the line with w.Prompt();

```
Sub ShellSort( ar( ) As String )
   Dim Lower As Integer
   Dim Upper As Integer
   Dim botMax As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim k As Integer
   Dim h As Integer
   Dim v As String

   Lower% = Lbound( ar$( ) )
   Upper% = Ubound( ar$( ) )

   h% = 1
   Do
      h% = (3*h%) + 1
      Loop Until h% > Upper%-Lower%+1
         Do
            h% = h% \ 3
            botMax% = Lower% + h% - 1
            For i% = botMax% + 1 To Upper%
               v$ = ar$( i% )
               k% = i%
               While ar$( k% - h% ) > v$
                  ar$( k% ) = ar$( k% - h% )
                  k% = k% - h%
                  If (k% <= botMax%) Then Goto wOut
               Wend
wOut:
   If (k% <> i%) Then ar$(k%) = v$
      Next
      Loop Until h% = 1
End Sub
```

(source: http://www.dominoexperts.com/articles/Very-fast-sorting-algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Sort` in a Evaluate call to get the folder names sorted.

```vb
Dim foldersList As String
Dim folders As Variant
...
ForAll v In dbSource.Views
    If v.IsFolder Then
        foldersList = foldersList + |:"| + Replace(Replace(v.Name, |\|, |\\|), |"|, |\"|) + |"|
    End If
End ForAll
If foldersList <> "" then
    folders = Evaluate(|@Sort(| + StrRight(foldersList, ":") + |)|)
    ...
```

The code above works this way:

First collect all folder names in a string as a formula list like

```
"xyz":"abc":"mno":"def"
```

Make sure that quotation marks in folder names are replaced by `\"` and backslashes for subfolders are replaced by `\\`.

Second evaluate a formula with `@Sort("xyz":"abc":"mno":"def")`.

The result is a sorted variant string array you can use in your `w.Prompt(..., ..., folders(0), folders )` like before.

The benefit of this solution is a very short code and it is fast too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I might try to compare the performance of this and the "pure" ls way.

Comment: Performance might not be the point here as you probably won't have hundreds or thousands of folders. I added this approach more because it is an easy way to use the existing sorting function in Lotus Notes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a list instead of an array then the values will be automatically placed in a sorted order. eg.

```
Dim folders List As Boolean
ForAll v In dbSource.Views
  If (v.IsFolder) Then folders(v.Name) = True 
End ForAll
```

Comment: List items are not automatically sorted, they are stored in the order they are created...